# Embedding python classes with different input function to C

Tags: python, c, function, class, embedding

So, I have followed the instructions from [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I?fid=220123&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=51#xx0xx)
I changed several parts because I want to access many classes in python codes with different functions.
For learning, I modified the codes from the link above into:

```
class Multiply: 

    def __init__(self): 
         self.a = 6 
         self.b = 5 

   def multiply(self):
         c = self.a*self.b
         print 'The result of', self.a, 'x', self.b, ':', c
         return c

   def multiply2(self, a, b, d):
        e = a*b*d
        print 'The result of', a, 'x', b, 'x', d, e
        return e

class Add:      
   def multiply3(self, k, l):
       f = k+l
       print 'The result of', k, '+', l, ':', f
       return f
```

And modified some parts of the call_class.c from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I?fid=220123&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=51#xx0xx) into

```
pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, argv[3], "(iii)", arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);
```

After compiling the call_function.c and try to call multiply3 from Add class, I got this error `TypeError: multiply3() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`

I know it is because of that pValue, but I just think how could I call those classes with different functions input.
I just wonder some solutions:
 1. Should I create more than one pValue?
2. Should I create more than one call_class.c for calling different python classes (but no efficient at all)?

Any suggestions is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: As the error message says, you're passing `multiply3()` with too many arguments. `pInstance` becomes the first argument `self`, and `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` are `k` and `l` -- total 3 arguments. You should be able to use the existing code following the `// Call a method of the class with two parameters` comment in order to call the `Add.multiply3()` method.